# How can I distinguish end of line comments from full line comments in ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, yaml, ruamel.yaml

In an attempt to make complex Azure DevOps pipelines self-documenting I am trying to read comments out of YAML files automatically. I have decided to use the `ruamel.yaml` python library.

Reading comments works well, but I have not found how to distinguish comments at the end of the line from full-line comments:

```
  - book # This is an end-of-the-line comment
    # This is a full line comment
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Code example, reading the stage-level comments of all stages, without comments of sub-entities of stages:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap, CommentedSeq

file_name = 'test.yaml'

yaml=YAML()
with open(file_name) as doc:
    data = yaml.load(doc)

i = 0
for item in data['stages']:
    i+=1
    print("*** stage", i, item['stage'])
    if isinstance(item, CommentedMap):
        comment_token = item.ca.items.get('stage')
        stage_help = {"stage_id": i}
        current_key = "Comment"
        if comment_token:
            for tab in comment_token:
                if tab:
                    vals = tab.value.split('\n')

                    for line in vals:
                        if line[1:1] == "#":
                            line = line[1:]
                        else:
                            line = line.strip()[1:].strip()
                        if len(line) == 0:
                            continue
                        if line[0:1] == "@":
                            current_key = line[1:line.index(':')]
                            content = line[line.index(':')+1:].strip()
                        else:
                            content = line
                        if current_key not in stage_help:
                            stage_help[current_key] = f"{content}"
                        else:
                            stage_help[current_key] = f"{stage_help[current_key]}\n{content}"

                    print(stage_help)
```

YAML:

```
stages:
  - stage: TestA
    # @Comment: I write what it does
    # @Link: https://documentation
  - stage: TestB # My favorite stage!
    # @Comment: We can also write
    # Multiline docs
    # @Link: https://doc2
    displayName: Test B # The displayName is shown in the pipeline's GUI
```

Running this gives me:

```
*** stage 1 TestA
{'stage_id': 1, 'Comment': 'I write what it does', 'Link': 'https://documentation'}
*** stage 2 TestB
{'stage_id': 2, 'Comment': 'My favorite stage!\nWe can also write\nMultiline docs', 'Link': 'https://doc2'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the ruamel.yaml package [indicates](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) that:

> The 0.17 series will also see changes in how comments are attached during
> roundtrip. This will result in backwards incompatibilities on the `.ca` data
> and it might even be necessary for documented methods that handle comments.

so you should certainly test for the version of the installed ruamel.yaml in your code.

In ruamel.yaml<0.17. Any comment only lines (and empty lines) are attached to the preceding
end-of-line comment that is associated with a napping key (or sequence element
index). If such a preceding end-of-line comment doesn't exists, it is constructed as just a newline. That
is what you should check for

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

assert ruamel.yaml.version_info < (0, 17)

yaml_str = """\
stages:
  - stage: TestA
    # @Comment: I write what it does
    # @Link: https://documentation
  - stage: TestB # My favorite stage!
    # @Comment: We can also write
    # Multiline docs
    # @Link: https://doc2
    displayName: Test B # The displayName is shown in the pipeline's GUI
"""

def comment_splitter(comment_list):
     """ expects the list that is a comment attached to key/index as argument
     returns a tuple containing;
     - the eol comment for the key/index (empty string if not available)
     - a list of, non-empty, full comments lines following the key/index
     """
     token = comment_list[2]
     # print(token)
     eol, rest = token.value.split('\n', 1)
     return eol.strip(), [y for y in [x.strip() for x in rest.split('\n')] if y]

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(comment_splitter(data['stages'][0].ca.items.get('stage')))
print(comment_splitter(data['stages'][1].ca.items.get('stage')))
```

which gives:

```
('', ['# @Comment: I write what it does', '# @Link: https://documentation'])
('# My favorite stage!', ['# @Comment: We can also write', '# Multiline docs', '# @Link: https://doc2'])
```

Because you immediately split the value of the `CommentToken` (if available) in your program and just skip
if the line is of zero length, you probably missed this. If you uncomment the `# print(token)` this should become clear.

---

I recommend against abusing YAML comments this way, and instead ask to consider *generating* the file that azure pipelines
expects by extracting the information from a more complete YAML file with a small python program. That is how I overcome
the deficiencies of the `docker-compose.yaml` file format.

Whether you check in the resulting (simpler) YAML, or always generate
it on the fly depends on the capabilities of the pipeline cq. how you invoke it.

I would probably start with something like following, and process that:

```
stages:
  - @Stage
    name: TestA
    comment: I write what it does
    link: https://documentation
  - @Stage
    name: TestB # My favorite stage!
    Comment: |
        We can also write
        Multiline docs
    link: https://doc2
    displayName: Test B # The displayName is shown in the pipeline's GUI
```

That way you don't have to deal with any changes in the way comments will be attached in future versions of ruamel.yaml.